# What are the important properties of automorphism group $\mathrm{Aut}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, automorphism-group

I want to know

> What are the most important and basic properties of automorphism group $\mathrm{Aut}$ of a group (or any other objects)?
>
> Which kind of information of main group the automorphism group can recover?

maybe it is better for me to solve some interesting problems about automorphism group in order to learn something about it. Any good references?